# Extract Joomla page titles using php script

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, page-title

I am trying to design a form to be used in Joomla to edit page titles when logged in as a front end admin.

I have written the following which lists all the articles on the website :

```
    <h3>Edit Page Titles</h3>
    <table border="0" style="text-align:left;">
      <tr style="text-align:left;">
        <th style="text-align:left;" width="400px"  scope="col">ID</th>
        <th style="text-align:left;" width="400px"  scope="col">Name</th>
     <th style="text-align:left;" width="400px"  scope="col">Params</th>
    <th style="text-align:left;" width="400px"  scope="col">Delete</th>
      </tr>
    <?php
    if (JFactory::getUser()->id == 0)
        die("Access denied: login required.");
        else
    {
    $today = date("d-m-y");
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ymeg_menu ORDER BY id")or die(mysql_error());

    echo '<tr style="text-align:left;">';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      {
        echo '<td style="text-align:left;">';  
      echo $row['id'];
      echo '</td>'; 
      echo '<td style="text-align:left;">'; 
      echo $row['name'];
         echo '</td>'; 

      echo '<td style="text-align:left;">'; 
      echo $row['params'];
         echo '</td>';

    echo '<td>';
    echo '<a href="index.php?option=com_chronoforms&chronoform=DeleteTagsAction&token=';
    echo $row['id'];
    echo '"style="color:#AD0F02 !important; font-weight:bold !important;">Delete</a>';
    echo '</td>';
      echo "</tr>";
      }
      }
      ?>


    </table>
```

When the script is run, in the params column is listed something similar to the following for each page on the site :

```
        num_leading_articles=1 num_intro_articles=0 num_columns=1 num_links=0 orderby_pri= orderby_sec=order multi_column_order=1 show_pagination=2 show_pagination_results=1 show_feed_link=1 show_noauth=0 show_title=0 link_titles=0 show_intro=1 show_section=0 link_section=0 show_category=0 link_category=0 show_author=1 show_create_date=1 show_modify_date=1 show_item_navigation=0 show_readmore=1 show_vote=0 show_icons=1 show_pdf_icon=1 show_print_icon=1 show_email_icon=1 show_hits=1 feed_summary= fusion_item_subtext= fusion_customimage= fusion_customclass= fusion_columns=1 fusion_distribution=even fusion_dropdown_width=290 fusion_column_widths= fusion_children_group=0 fusion_children_type=menuitems splitmenu_item_subtext= suckerfish_item_subtext= page_title=SOS Direct – Motorcycle Breakdown Cover From The Motorcycle Breakdown Experts show_page_title=0 pageclass_sfx= menu_image=-1 secure=0
```

The part I am trying to extract is : page_title=SOS Direct – Motorcycle Breakdown Cover From The Motorcycle Breakdown Experts

Does anyone know how to extract the above from the returned results so that in the params column all I would get would be something similar to "SOS Direct – Motorcycle Breakdown Cover From The Motorcycle Breakdown Experts" ?.

Comment: what version of Joomla are you using? also, I wouldn't use `ymeg_menu`, I would use `#__menu`

Comment: Its version 1.5 , thanks, I was using #_ a moment ago and it wouldnt work, I didnt realise I needed the extra _ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$params = new JParameter( $row['params'] );
$title = $params->get('page_title');
```

The only parameter in the constructor of JParameter is the INI-data.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this but just get a blank params coulumn.

Comment: Ahh sorry, my mistake, I forgot to add echo $title; , I have added this and it works for the first entry (the home page), all other entries though are blank ?.

Comment: Sorry I just realised it is actually working, the reason they wernt showing up was because I had show_title set to 1 so it was using the article title instead of the menu item title, thanks !.